# Backbone.js. prevent GET

Tags: backbone.js

Im working on an application where i have found this weird problem. When i init my Model both GET and POST triggers. Its only supposed to trigger a POST, since i run `Model.save();`

What can be the problem here?

Here is the Model:

```
PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
url: function() { 
    return "/api?action=answerQuestion"+"&question_id="+this.get('questionId')+"&option_id=" + this.get('optionId')+"&type=" + this.get('role');
},  

defaults: {
    questionId: 0,
    optionId: 0,
    role: 0
}
```

});

Here is where the model gets created. (on a click event).

```
    events: {
    'click li': 'answerQuestion'
},

answerQuestion: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
    });
    $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

    var currentQuestion = 1;
    var answer = parseInt($(event.currentTarget).find('a').attr('data-answer'));
    var role = 1;

    var postModel = new PostModel();
    postModel.set({ 
        questionId: currentQuestion, 
        optionId: answer, 
        role: role
    });

    postModel.save();
}
```

Comment: I know it's irrelevant, but may I ask why your url for your model looks like that ? would it be cleaner to do a post request to your server instead of passing the params in the url?

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Ve9h4/2/